# DataFrame to JSON format, using column value as value

Tags: python, json, pandas, to-json

I want to output the format of JSON, which is like:

```
{"553588913747808256":"rumour","524949003834634240":"rumour","553221281181859841":"rumour","580322346508124160":"non-rumour","544307417677189121":"rumour"}
```

Here, I have a `df_prediction_with_id` dataFrame and I `set_index` using the `id_str`:

```
df_prediction_with_id

                   rumor_or_not
id_str  
552800070199148544  non-rumour
544388259359387648  non-rumour
552805970536333314  non-rumour
525071376084791297  rumour
498355319979143168  non-rumour
```

What I've tried is to use [DataFrame.to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html).

```
json = df_prediction_with_id.to_json(orient='index')
```

What I've got is:

```
{"552813420136128513":{"rumor_or_not":"non-rumour"},"544340943965409281":{"rumor_or_not":"non-rumour"}}
```

Is there any way that I could directly use the value in the column as the value? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply select the column and call `.to_json()`:

```
print(df_prediction_with_id["rumor_or_not"].to_json())
```

Prints:

```json
{"552800070199148544":"non-rumour","544388259359387648":"non-rumour","552805970536333314":"non-rumour","525071376084791297":"rumour","498355319979143168":"non-rumour"}
```